# Не работает то pip, то install

Tags: python, pip, install

Хочу значит установить opencv-python и xtermcolor, захожу в cmd, пишу py, пишу pip install opencv-python. Результат:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install opencv-python
        ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Я читал, что если не работает, попробуйте установить pip, результат:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -m pip install -U pip
              ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Что делать?

Comment: «пишу py» — а вот не надо было это делать

Comment: Почему? Что такого в py? У меня py запускает Python, а у тебя что?

Comment: А вот не надо было запускать Python. pip — это программа, которую нужно запускать в cmd без всяких питонов

Comment: "pip" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Ну тогда `python -m pip` например

Comment: C:\Users\Дима\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: No module named pip

Comment: Значит вы криво установили Python, забыв поставить галочку pip в процессе установки

Comment: Я его с какой то версии обновлял, и такой галочки не было

Comment: Удалю и установлю значит

Comment: Удалил и установил с галочкой pip - тоже самое

Comment: python -m pip - python -m **pip**

Answer (score 0):

Переустановите Python и не забудьте проверить галочку во время установки перед строкой pip, когда предлагают выбрать дополнения. Еще может быть проблема в пути, где установлен Python, можете попробовать изменить его. И если вы когда-нибудь устанавливали python и удаляли, то поищите старые файлы и удалите их.

Answer (score 0):

В cmd напиши следующее `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Все верно, но только нужно повторить то же самое не вводя py в начале. И проверьте что pip у вас добавлен в PATH("pip" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом - иначе вот такая ошибка может быть). А так получается что вы пытаетесь установить opencv через скрипт на питоне)