# Попытка установить модуль Python

Tags: python, модули

Я пытаюсь установить вообще любой модуль. Пробовал так как писали в источниках

```
pip install pygame
```

Но в результате выходит следующее:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Пробовал и так:

```
python pip install pygame
```

Но получается следующий результат

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Я либо упускаю мелкий момент, либо ни черта не понимаю. На помощь!
Python v3.10.4 (64 bit)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1423681/178576 — ваш вопрос?

Comment: @Дмитрий python -m pip install pygame // Может сработает, а может и нет)

Comment: вот этот вопрос даже лучше как дубликат: [Не работает pip install в Питон консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/792697/178576)

Comment: Man4, Попытка произведена
Результат - FAIL

Comment: Man4, Я разобрался с проблемой. Просто, почему-то нигде не упомянули, кроме здесь, про cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ - cmd.
Я думал, что нужно в самом Python вводить команды. А нужно в командной строке.
Но в источниках нигде не упомянули cmd. Либо я просто слепой